# How to get rid of dnsmasq listening at 0.0.0.0:67/UDP which isn't started via systemd?

Tags: networking, network-manager, systemd, 17.04, dnsmasq

I'm debugging an issue on my "WiFi router" (firmware bug or network configuration mistake) and would like to selectively turn off potential error sources in my LAN. After disabling the `dnsmasq.service` `systemd` unit, rebooting and confirming that the `systemd` unit is disabled, I still see

```
udp  0  0 0.0.0.0:67  0.0.0.0:*  5382/dnsmasq
```

in `sudo netstat -tupln | grep :67`. I can kill the instance with `sudo pkill dnsmasq`, however, I'd like to understand where it comes because I it's strange in my understanding that a system service like `dnsmasq` is started outside the control of `systemd`. Then I'd like to adjust my configuration so that the unwanted `dnsmasq` instance is no longer started. I'm using `network-manager` for my network configuration.

I'm using Ubuntu 17.04.

Comment: I believe that has to do with [libvirt](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/libvirt.html) if you have like qemu installed.  Try running `ps -ef | grep 5382` and see if it is tied to `libvirt`.

Comment: I believe `network-manager` can start `dnsmasq`, at least in some cases.  See: https://superuser.com/a/847089 .  Also, are you (intentionally) running `dnsmasq` as a DHCP server?  I ask because `dnsmasq` is listening on `0.0.0.0:67`.